# Can the mid-2010 Macbook be used with the Apple Remote?

Tags: macbook-pro, remote-control

I know that the remote works with units that have an IR sensor. The system profile has listings for hardware that both is and is not installed but, I don't see a listing for an IR unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting 2010 it is only the Macbook Pro's that support IR.

The last Macbook that supported IR was the 13" mid 2009, and the last Macbook Air was mid 2009

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure since I've seen some models with concealed sensors.